# Why do +MOD before %MOD?

Tags: c++17

Question Link : https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/contest/gfg-weekly-coding-contest-139/problems
( 3rd Question )

`sum = (sum%M - E[x-1]%M)%M`   or  `sum = (sum-E[x-1])%M` didn't work but
`sum = (sum-E[x-1]+M)%M` works.

what is the benefit of +Mod before % Mod ?

```
class Solution {
  public:
    int MaximumEnergy(int n, vector<int> &E, int K, vector<int> &P) {
        
        // code here
        int M = 1e9+7;
        int ans = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i<n; i++) E[i] = (E[i]+E[i-1])%M;
        
        sort(P.begin(), P.end());
        for(int i = 0, j = K-1; i<K/2; i++){
            int x = P[i], y = P[j]; j--;
            int sum = E[y];


            if(x>0) sum = ((sum%M)-(E[x-1]%M))%M;
            // if(x>0) sum = (sum-E[x-1]+M)%M;


            ans = (ans+sum)%M;
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're trying to solve in the question?

Comment: If a<b, (a-b)%M is different from (a-b+M)%M -- either look at the definition of the operator % or take some example values, do the computations, print them out, and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People who are not logged in at geeks for geeks cannot see the questions, so it's gard to say anything specific.

But assuming that `E[i]` will be `>= 0` and seeing that both, `sum` and `E[i]` are always less than `M` (because they are always calculated `%M)`the expression `(sum-E[x-1]+M)` is always positive, whereas `((sum%M)-(E[x-1]%M))` might also get negative. And depending on the result of `x%M` for a negative `x` (different programming languages interpret this differently) you might get different outcomes.

Comment: hmm, if  `sum` and `E[i]`  < `M`, wouldn't `(sum-E[x-1]+M)%M` be just equal to `abs(sum-E[x-1])` for C++ ?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie yeah, it would.